# How do I automate a Windows 8 (x86) tablet setup process?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, installation

I'm using Windows 8 tablets in a manufacturing environment.  I have to go through a rather lengthy setup process to get everything to work.  Does anyone know how to automate all of this process.  I know that Advanced Installer can do a lot for me already, but it doesn't do everything.

The setup process's steps are outlined in the link below:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/10SzuLGtJZ3AMhwPhGiK0NfUR-1HNx4dSwTg-hyXG3qE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I've found to automate this process is using a macro utility such as Automation Anywhere.